# C# Access, How to Perform a query from a view in access

Tags: c#, ms-access

Im using Visual Studio 2012 and access 2010 as a storage and I create a view(queries) in access.  Im perform the query using visual studio im the system dont return any value, however i verify this query in access and it works.  I think that Visual studio dont recognize that im trying to perform a query to a View(queries) and not from to table section.

Here is the code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connString;
OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
string query = "SELECT [Part Number], [Serial Number], TestReading, Adjusment FROM Output 
Where    [Test Date] = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+"'";
cmd.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adap.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

OleDbConnections do allow you to query Views.

If it's not throwing an error then it is working, just not returning data. Try putting a breakpoint in there and copying the query to run in Access.

The first thing I'd check though is the format [Test Date]. If it's a date, you need to wrap the date with # signs. I would edit this line.

```
string query = "SELECT [Part Number], [Serial Number], TestReading, Adjusment FROM Output Where [Test Date] = #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+"#";
```